# Conversion between co-ordinate systems

Tags: matlab, cartesian-coordinates

I have a set of data coordinates in 3D with respect to an Origin, say O1, and another set of data that represents the same movements but in 2D with respect to an Origin, say O2. What can I do to calculate the transformations that are required to implement on the 3D set to be able to compare the data points(2D vs 3D) in a 2D frame?

[Setup of data generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbaq.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at transformation matrices? You can do this easily with those. If you want to calculate the matrix from the known coordinate systems, you can do it solving a linear system of equations

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes i have looked up on transformation matrices and change of basis and vector transformations etc but can't see how I can relate them to this problem. The coordinate system of the 2D is just a position I chose from a video that is tracked by Kinovea and the data points given are relevant to that point. The 3D system is a VICON system which has a volumetric centre and the data points are related to that. I need to get these tracks close to each other so that i can anaylse and compare them

Comment: Shift both to a common origin and rotate the 3-D system so that two of its axes are aligned with the axes of the 2-D system.

Comment: The unique reason of existence of transformation matrices is transforming a data set on coordinate system OXYZ to O'X'Y'Z', which is literally what you want to do. What of that does not relate to your problem?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 how can I know the angle of rotation? there is no way i can find that out , yes?

Comment: Do you know the correspondence between the 3D and 2D points? Do you know the intrinsic parameters of the camera?

Comment: @lcrt_9 You do not know how either coordinate system is defined?

Comment: @AnderBiguri
I have drawn something similar to what the setup of data capture was. The only thing that was fixed obviously was the person that I tracked his movements both in 2D with the camera whos position with respect to the 3D origin I know (-3131,302,1366)

Comment: @AnonSUbmitter85 see above

Comment: @lcrt_9 So you know the origin of both the 3-D and the 2-D systems, but you do not know the orientation of either's axes?

Comment: A 2D coordinate system is a 3D coordinate system in where you only use 1 value of Z (z=0). Just with this you can use transformation matrices to convert from one to the other

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 exactly

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, i have understood that concept well. Though, with what should I multiply the vector with ? Do i have to know any more data or the ones that I have are sufficient to be able to shift the origins onto each other?

Comment: @AnderBiguri ::

Comment: I assume that each location has a time associated with it too?

Comment: Yes, each frame has a time according to it and obviously diffferent coordinates. The system was set up appropriately to be able to syncronize the frames exactly together.

Answer (score 0):

If the measurements are at the same times, then the following might work. I have not actually tried it and make no claim that it is the best solution, but it seems doable. Basically, after adjusting the coordinates so that they have the same origin, you want to minimize the following 2-norm:

```
|| vec(A*x) - vec(P*B*y) ||
```

where `x` is the 2xN array of the 2-D locations, `A` is a 2x2 rotation matrix that rotates `x` by the unknown angle `theta`, `P` is a 2x3 projection matrix that projects a 3x1 vector onto its first two dimensions (viz., just throws out the third value), `B` is a 3x3 rotation matrix, and `y` is the 3xN array of the 3-D locations.

The unknowns in the above are `theta` in the 2-D rotation matrix, and the three rotation angles needed to define `B`. The four angles that minimize the above should (at least I think) give you the rotation matrices needed to align the coordinate systems.